# How to convert String to int dynamically (Reflection API)

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to do this:

```
Field field = classeDoObjetoDaColecao.getDeclaredField(caminho[0]);

//Here I get the setMethod, based on the attribute (via field)
Method metodoSet = classeDoObjetoDaColecao.getMethod(partesLista[0], field.getType());


metodoSet.invoke(objetoNovo,field.getType().cast(value));
```

Where `value` is a `String`and field` is a primitive int.

This generates an exception that `String` can't be cast to `int`.

Comment: Casting doesn't change an object.

Comment: You won't use reflection for the conversion. You'll use `Integer.parseInt(..)` after figuring out that it's a `String` which you want to convert to an `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Answer. You cant cast String to int.

try to use

```
    Integer.parseInt(String);
```

An Cast dont convert an Object. It just specify it.

For example you haven a Superclass with 2 Subclasses.

The you can cast from Super to Subclass.

Answer (score 0):

There's no dynamic way to do this. You need to establish that you have a field of type `int` or `Integer` and a value of type `String` which you want to convert.

Once you have that, you can use `Integer.parseInt(..)` to do the conversion.

If you then want to add other conversion pairs, you need to do the same thing. Find the source and target type and do the appropriate conversion based on those types.